# Formatting Dojo TextBox on the fly

Tags: dojo

I want to format the value of any type of TextBox, based on a pattern, on the fly. So basicly I mean when the user is typing `'123'` and my pattern is `'0.00'` it has to be converted directly to '1.23'. I know I can do this with the `onChange` function, but I guess there is already a Dojo based solution(not the `onChange` of a TextBox). Could someone tell me which property I have to use?

I've tried to use `constraints` and `filter`, but both only work after a blur event.

Answer (score 0):

Widgets fire events on themselves that emulate the events of their DOM elements. For example a text box dijit will fire a change event on the object called "change".

There is also an replaceable function called "format" which, as the name suggests, formats the value of the text box.

see: http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/form/_TextBoxMixin

As such you can do:

```
widget.format = function(value, constraints){ //my formatting fnc}

widget.on('change', function(){
    widget.format();
});
```

Comment: I know there is a format function, but this only fires after a blur. I know I could use `on('change', function(){})` but I was hoping that there was a more elegant way to fix this. At the moment I'm trying to use `pattern`(regex), but the problem is that I only can set a pattern like `\d{1,3},?\d{0,2}`. This gives me the expected result(??d,??), but when a user doesn't set the decimals the textbox must automatically add '00'. Like the `constraints: {places: '2'}` function. The problem is that `places` and `constraints` doesn't work at the same time.